# What is it called when you are asked to re-authenticate using credentials to perform a sensitive operation?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor-authentication

This is a simple question about terminology.

I know that when MFA is used after login and prior to allowing a sensitive operation, it's referred to as "step-up". However, some applications simply ask for your password once more instead. An example is Github asking for your password prior to you changing some repo settings.

Does the "step-up" term also encompass asking for credentials or password again? If not, what is that called? "Re-authentication"?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. TL;DR: Reauthentication (no dash)

I was recently researching this and came upon your question. Here's how I approached the question, and what I discovered.

I was looking for what to call the design pattern where, once you’ve logged in, if you want to access something like credit card, banking, or other secure, PII, you must first enter your password a 2nd time (once per session) before you can access the protected information.

As you mentioned, it’s sort of like 2FA, but you’re using the same factor twice (password).

An example I see daily is on my Mac, which is encrypted with FileVault, so I login (decrypt) then login again (actual login). Or on banking sites where you log in to authenticate and gain access, but then you must enter your PW a second time during that session to see/do any real transactions.

Google calls this pattern “Authentication” (e.g. when requiring a 2nd pw entry to buy something on a device) which seems WAY too vague for me. So I dug deeper. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1626831?hl=en

IBM calls it "Forced Reauthentication" https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sva/9.0?topic=reauthentication-concepts

And lastly, NIST.gov calls it "Fixed Periodic Reauthentication" https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf

So really, it's just reauthentication.